# Configuring postfix to work with TLS (mediawiki)

Tags: postfix, smtp, tls

I have a couple of questions regarding postfix config. First of all I need TLS as of the pear smtp plugin mediawiki uses, forces TLS authentication.

- Will it work on 25? Or what's the advised port?
- Do I need multiple certifications for different domains? Or is it mailserver specific?
- Can I / Do I have to use the same certs that my webserver uses?

By the way I'm at this stage:

```
Failed to set sender: x@y.z [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 530, response: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first)]
```

Even though the same certs dovecot uses are set in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, they don't seem to work.

Comment: This looks like a configuration problem with the MediaWiki plugin. It should be using STARTTLS.

Answer (score 1):

Michael was right, there is a bug in the `net_smtp` pear module. MediaWiki could be configured to disregard the default settings and not try to mess with TLS emails. This is not the right answer, the emails are not getting encrypted at all, but at least get sent.

In LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgSMTP = false;
$wgEmailAuthentication = false;
```

Comment: Thanks to pointing me to these settings. I've made an entry in [Manual talk:$wgSMTP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:$wgSMTP#Using_Sendmail_or_Postfix_(on_Ubuntu/Linux)).